# How can I create a customer and a charge at the same time within the stripe API?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to create a customer and charge him at the same time with stripe.

I've done that for the moment, but I'm obliged to send the $token 2 times..
If I only do the charge, I can't see it in my stripe test backend and if I only do the custoer creation, it creates itself but doesn't charge him...
I'm a bit lost

here's my code :

```
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];

\Stripe\Customer::create([
  "source" => $token,
  "email" => $email
    ]);

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
'amount' => 999,
'currency' => 'usd',
'description' => 'Example charge',
'source' => $token,
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this, create the Customer, then charge the Customer (rather than the token):

```
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];


// Create a Customer:
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
    'source' => $token,
    'email' => $email,
]);

// Charge the Customer instead of the source
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
    'amount' => 1000,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'customer' => $customer->id,
]);
```

See https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards